# Ports in the pod and not the same as in the deployment descriptor

Tags: kubernetes

We have found that the ports defined in our daemonset deployment descriptor are not reflected in the running pods.
The image we are using is NGINX, and we routed these host ports to 80 and 8080:

```
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 30003
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 30002
```

Nothing wrong there, and the deployment history shows those ports are active in the pod:

```
daemonset.extensions/nginx-licensed with revision #25
Pod Template:
  Containers:
   nginx-licensed:
    Image:  nginx-licensed:1.0.117
    Ports:  80/TCP, 8080/TCP
    Host Ports: 30003/TCP, 30002/TCP
```

We wanted to change the host port used, and to allow the infrastructure changes to be made gradually, we assigned both old and new host ports to the same container ports:

```
        ports:
        - name: new80
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 20003
        - name: old80
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 30003
        - name: new8080
          containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 20002
        - name: old8080
          containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 30002
```

At this point, 'kubectl apply' results in only the 2000x ports being active:

```
daemonset.extensions/nginx-licensed with revision #26
Pod Template:
  Containers:
   nginx-licensed:
    Image:  nginx-licensed:1.0.119
    Ports:  80/TCP, 8080/TCP
    Host Ports: 20003/TCP, 20002/TCP
```

Note that if we restarted the pods, all four ports become active:

```
daemonset.extensions/nginx-licensed with revision #1
Pod Template:
  Containers:
   nginx-licensed:
    Image:  nginx-licensed:1.0.119
    Ports:  80/TCP, 80/TCP, 8080/TCP, 8080/TCP
    Host Ports: 20003/TCP, 30003/TCP, 20002/TCP, 30002/TCP
```

*However*, if we don't restart the pods, and try to remove the 3000x pods, i.e. this:

```
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 20003
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 20002
```

We end up with *no* container ports! :

```
daemonset.extensions/nginx-licensed with revision #27
Pod Template:
  Containers:
   nginx-licensed:
    Image:  nginx-licensed:1.0.119
    Ports:  80/TCP, 8080/TCP
    Host Ports: 0/TCP, 0/TCP
```

Any ideas why that is, or what we've done wrong? We rolled back to the version with four ports defined (i.e. both 2000x and 3000x), and that's resulted in just the 2000x host ports active.

Does this look like a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: What cloud provider are you using and what is the version of your kubernetes and kubectl?

Comment: I can replicate the problem on an OpenStack environment, with these versions
`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.2", GitCommit:"cff46ab41ff0bb44d8584413b598ad8360ec1def", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-10T23:35:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.2", GitCommit:"cff46ab41ff0bb44d8584413b598ad8360ec1def", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-10T23:28:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
`

Comment: As a point of interest, if I use 'kubectl apply' on the last deployment descriptor -which caused the host ports to disappear - the host ports are correctly set

Comment: What is the version of your kubernetes? `$ kubectl version`

Comment: The output from `kubectl version` is given in my reply above - 1.13.2 for both server and client, from what I can see. Sorry, I didn't make it clear it was the kubernetes version rather than OpenStack

Comment: My answer helped you? If yes, don't forget to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario on GKE and I have the same symptoms as you.

There is a way to achieve what you need and for that you need to [patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) your objects. You need to use the patch type  `merge-patch+json` and as a patch you need to supply a complete/desired list of containerPort.

Firstly you need to export your yaml file and make the necessary changes:

```
$ kubectl get deployments <your-deployment> -o yaml --export > patch-file.yaml
```

After making the changes, patch it:

```
$ kubectl patch deployments <your-deployment> --type merge --patch "$(cat patch-file.yaml)"
```

After doing this, I have your desired state:

```sh
$ kubectl describe deployments nginx-deployment | grep -i ports
    Ports:        80/TCP, 80/TCP, 8080/TCP, 8080/TCP
    Host Ports:   20003/TCP, 30003/TCP, 20002/TCP, 30002/TCP
```

If you want to deep dive into how this is working in the background refer to documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) and [here](http://erosb.github.io/post/json-patch-vs-merge-patch/).

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue, it's useful to know that it can be replicated. And thanks for the links too!